# What is this all-white insect?

Tags: identification, insects

I found this insect while looking for bugs in a relative's garden. Its body seems to be entirely white. It has large wings and is capable of flight.

I have no indication it's harming the plant; I just want to find a name for it because it is so beautiful.

Is this picture enough for anyone to identify?

[image: mysterious insect perched on plant]

Comment: What is the plant you found this thing amongst? The image doesn't magnify very well, but it looks like its got white fluff at what is presumably the head end, and seems only to have 2 pairs of legs... is that correct? Did you actually see it fly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The white insect in your photo may be considered a garden pest, though often it depends on how many of them are present. It is yet another member of a VERY diverse group of "Hemiptera" insects known as "leafhoppers" or "planthoppers". All members of this group of insects feed on plant sap. Many species of this group are relatively harmless. Some are quite beautiful. However, some species can cause damage to foliage, while others can and do spread diseases. Only you can decide if this one is a concern in the garden. Below are some links that might be helpful.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leafhopper

http://www.missouribotanicalgarden.org/gardens-gardening/your-garden/help-for-the-home-gardener/advice-tips-resources/pests-and-problems/insects/hoppers-and-leafhoppers/leafhoppers-and-planthoppers.aspx

http://butterflies.heuristron.net/bugs/whiteLeafhopper.html